# iOS/Objective-C: Call AlertViewController from sharedInstance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertviewcontroller

I am updating some UIAlertViews, deprecated since iOS 9.0 to UIAlertViewControllers.

With UIAlertView, it was possible to just throw an alert from any code being executed--even in a utility class or shared instance--with the simple line:

```
[alertView show];
```

So if I call a shared instance such as

```
- (void)didTapDeleteButton:(id)sender {
    NSArray *itemsToDelete = [self.selectedIndexPathToContact allValues];

    [[IDModel sharedInstance] deleteItems:itemsToDelete];
```

//which contains the code:

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Keep Archive Copy?"
                                                    message:nil
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"No"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"OK",nil];
alertInvite.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleDefault;
alertInvite.tag=100;
[alertView show];
```

everything worked fine.

However, with the UIAlertController, this is not allowed. If you put the following code in the method of a class accessible via shared instance, when you get to presentViewController, it throws an error:

```
UIAlertController *alertView = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Delete Item?" message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction* yesButton = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
    [alertView dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}];

UIAlertAction* noButton = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Not Now" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
    [alertView dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}];

[alertView addAction:noButton];
[alertView addAction:yesButton];
if ([alertView respondsToSelector:@selector(setPreferredAction:)]) {
    [alertView setPreferredAction:yesButton];
}
//FOLLOWING THROWS ERROR
[self presentViewController:alertView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

on the last line, that the class (reached via a shared instance) does not have this method.  It seems you must use a more complicated way to throw alert. I've seen some [somwehat convoluted approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38771374/present-controller-from-another-class-in-objective-c) such as the following:

```
id rootViewController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController;
if([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
{
    rootViewController = ((UINavigationController *)rootViewController).viewControllers.firstObject;
}
if([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]])
{
    rootViewController = ((UITabBarController *)rootViewController).selectedViewController;
}
[rootViewController presentViewController:alertInvite animated:YES completion:nil];
```

However, this does not work for me as I don't think my shared instance has a rootviewcontroller.  Can anyone suggest a simple, straightforward way to do this?

Comment: What sharedInstance are you referring to? [Edit] your question (no comments) with a bit more context to where you need to call `[self presentViewController...`.

Comment: `self` in `[self presentViewController` must be a `UIViewController`

Comment: he said the sharedInstance doesnt have the present method, so Id deduce it is any random NSObject and not a VC

Comment: See additional code requested by @rmaddy

Comment: Yes, the sharedInstance is an NSObject

Comment: Unrelated to your immediate issue but do not attempt to dismiss the alert controller from any `UIAlertAction`. The alert is dismissed for you before the alert action handler is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an extension on UIViewController that allows me to create a new window and present a view controller from there. This allows me to present from any class, not just a view controller. Also, it prevents issues where you try to display an alert view from a view controller that is already presenting a view controller.

```
extension UIViewController {
    func presentFromNewWindow(animated: Bool = true, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        let window = newWindow()

        if let rootViewController = window.rootViewController {
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
            rootViewController.present(self, animated: animated, completion: completion)
        }
    }

    private func newWindow() -> UIWindow {
        let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let rootViewController = UIViewController()
        rootViewController.view.backgroundColor = .clear
        window.backgroundColor = .clear
        window.rootViewController = rootViewController
        window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert

        return window
    }
}
```

You can then use this method to present your Alert Controller (or any UIViewController):

```
alertViewController.presentFromNewWindow()
```

When you dismiss the alert view controller, it is removed from the view controller and the window is removed from the hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

to show an alert from any code I could think of doing:

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
[alert addAction: [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Yes" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil]];
alert.TitleColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

id<UIApplicationDelegate> delegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
UIViewController *vc = delegate.window.rootViewController;
[vc presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

---

#### Note:

Note that in most cases I would NOT do this. 
Non ui code shouldn't do ui! Which is likely also part of the reason why apple made the change: It encourages a proper model||view separation

Comment: Would you send a notification to the View Controller.  Or how would you tell the onscreen VC to throw the alert?

Comment: You can't just assume you can show the alert from the app's rootViewController. That could already be presenting a view controller.

Comment: you cant assume for a call to self either ;) yet the sample does too *hehe*
I grant you it might not be the right thing in all cases, and I thought my NOTE paragraph implied i didnt agree

Comment: the proper way is NOT to do it at all bbut keep the UI in the View&Controller not the model

Comment: That's what I'm asking.  If you put the alert code in the view controller, how should the model tell it to fire the alert?  A notification or can you suggest another way? The model is handling the interaction with core data.

Comment: Is use completion blocks or delegate protocols above notifications :) I’ll generally prefer this cause notifications can be hard to reason about

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite vague, I believe. But I think what you've been looking for is an example of presenting a `UIAlertController`. Is that correct? If so, continue reading...

Example:

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
[alert addAction: [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Yes" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil]];
alert.TitleColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

doc: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller

Comment: the problem the op has is that he is in a singleton . likely not a view controller